# Generating a random string of numbers

Tags: wordpress, string, loops, numbers

I was wondering how I could add code which continually generates different strings of numbers for visual effects, on a WordPress page, it is for a school project and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to do? what have you tried? please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am trying to generate a random loop of numbers on a WordPress page?

Comment: @Oscar Watson please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below to generate the random number:

```
function random_str($length, $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
{
    $str = '';
    $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $str .= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
    }
    return $str;
}
echo $a = random_str(12);
```